# Must a question have an answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have designed some mechanisms that makes private properties in a class to be inaccessible from other contexts using whatever methods. I want to know if it is really inaccessible given any code. Can I ask a question here to challenge for accessing the private properties? Or should I ask them on another StackExchange site (and where?)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask on StackOverflow.com, or security.stackexchange.com. Not here.